# Summarize the employees by net revenue and not order date?

Tags: sql

The sales director would like to reward the employees with net sales over $150,000 for the years 2015 and 2016 combined. The Sales Manager would like the resulting query to display the following columns: Employee ID, Employee Name (First and Last as one field), Total Net Sales per employee. (Both years should be combined into one number.)

[image]

Sort largest to smallest.

We cannot figure out how to combine the revenues by the employees.

```
select o.EmpID, EmpFName + ' ' + EmpLastName as "Employee Name"
    , sum((salesunitprice*quantitysold)-((salesunitprice*quantitysold)*ItemDiscount)) as "Net Sales"
from EMPLOYEE e
inner join ORDERS o on e.EmpID = o.EmpID
inner join SALES_INVOICE si on o.OrderID = si.OrderID
inner join SALES_INVOICE_DETAIL sd on si.SalesInvoiceID = sd.SalesInvoiceID
group by o.EmpID, EmpFName + ' ' + EmpLastName, OrderDate
having OrderDate between '2015-01-01' and '2016-12-31' 
order by [Employee Name]
```

I expected the output to be the total per employee, but it is broken out by individual order dates instead of summing the total net sales per employee.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Please show some sample data, results you are currently getting, and results you want.

Comment: Please show all data in text/tabular form not images.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `OrderDate` from the `GROUP BY`:

```
select o.EmpID, EmpFName + ' ' + EmpLastName as "Employee Name",
       sum(salesunitprice * quantitysold * (1 - discount)) as "Net Sales"
from EMPLOYEE e join
     ORDERS o
     on e.EmpID = o.EmpID join
     SALES_INVOICE si
     on o.OrderID = si.OrderID join
     SALES_INVOICE_DETAIL sd
     on si.SalesInvoiceID = sd.SalesInvoiceID
where o.OrderDate >= '2015-01-01' and
      o.OrderDate < '2017-01-01'
group by o.EmpID, EmpFName + ' ' + EmpLastName
having sum(salesunitprice * quantitysold * (1 - discount)) >= 150000
order by [Employee Name]
```

Notes:

- You want to do the date filtering *before* the aggregation.
- `BETWEEN` doesn't work with `datetime`s.  The formulation with `>=` and `<` works with both `date`s and `datetime`s.
- I have simplified the arithmetic to calculate net sales.
- The important part is removing the extra key in the `GROUP BY`.
- And you want a `having` clause to filter the net sales.